# how to add custom schema URL to "sms_body"

Tags: android, schema, sms

I want to send a sms message that contain custom schema URL :

For example:
              ***samuel://ace?id=dddfsdfsdfsdfs***

When the addressee clikc this URL, it will launch my application.

My question is that how can I add the hyperlink to "sms_body" ?

Any people have the relative experience ? In other words, Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-successfully-preset-body-copy-within-a-tap-to-SMS-link

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `samuel://ace?id=dddfsdfsdfsdfs`. Use `http://samuel.org/ace?id=dddfsdfsdfsdfs`. In your Android application, have an activity that responds to `ACTION_VIEW`, with the `BROWSEABLE` category, with an appropriate `<data>` element to match on the scheme, host, and path. Also create a Web page on your Web server that explains the value of your application and why they should install it.

This way:

- Your link will be clickable automatically
- Your link will work on all devices, including non-Android devices
- Your link will still open your desired activity when the user has your application installed

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler) showing some of this.

Comment: At first, thanks for your help. But I don't think this is a good solution.  <data android:scheme="http" android:path="samuel"/> When I click other http link, the device will provide a list，the list contain "Browser" and "MyApp", I don't want to let myapp response the action

Comment: @Samuel.Cai: You clearly have not tried the solution I outlined.