# how to make custom url clickable from sms in android

Tags: android, sms, custom-url

I want to open my application from custom url in sms in android. I have already made a custom url and I have associate an activity with this url, but the problem is that my url is not accessible from url in sms text. Please help me to make it accessible from sms text.

Comment: Have a look at this [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6508077/1050058)